# Could some one detail the Flume Command?

Tags: java, hadoop, flume

Could someone tell me the detailed description of below flume command to execute conf file.

```
bin/flume-ng agent --conf-file netcat_flume.conf --name a1
-Dflume.root.logger=INFO,console
```

As of my knowledge,

`--conf-file`  -> To specify Configuration File name or to mention to FLUME that we need to run this file.

`--name` -> Agent

But what below command does.?

```
-Dflume.root.logger=INFO,console
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Its the Log4j Property which is explained in detail below

**INFO** which means output only informational messages that highlight the progress of the application at coarse-grained level. For more details [check](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/log4j/log4j_logging_levels.htm)

**console** means output the log4j logs onto the console. Other options available are write to database and write to file.

```
  -Dflume.root.logger=INFO,console
```

**The above statement write coarse grained level logs of flume execution to console**

Comment: @Bala does this answer you query?

Comment: Yes it does. But Im little confused about this one. What does  
  -Dflume.root.logger this mean. I mean. In Sink we have logger,spooldir and another one I forget the name. What does this root.logger does.?

Answer (score 0):

The shell script flume-ng,accept args,finally run command like:

`java -Xmx20m -Dflume.root.logger=INFO,console -cp '=:/home/scy/apache-flume-1.4.0-bin/lib/*:/home/scy/apache-flume-1.4.0-bin/conf:/home/scy/jdk1.6.0_45/lib/tools.jar' -Djava.library.path= org.apache.flume.node.Application --conf-file conf/example.conf --name agent1 conf org.apache.flume.node`

Let's look at sourcecode  org.apache.flume.node.Application.main(String[] args):

```
PropertiesFileConfigurationProvider configurationProvider =
        new PropertiesFileConfigurationProvider(agentName,
            configurationFile);
```

Here class PropertiesFileConfigurationProvider accept agentName and configurationFile which specific by "--conf-file" and "--name"

Then application.start() run all source,channel and sink

As about `-Dflume.root.logger=INFO,console`,Let's look at flume/log4j.properties:

```
flume.root.logger=INFO,LOGFILE
```

flume.root.logger will changed by `-Dflume.root.logger=INFO,console`,it means put all info level logs to console